# How was game development done in C with no OOP?

Tags: c#, c, oop

Coming from a C# background, I've been wondering for a long time about how game development was done in a intermediate language like C. A lot of the old games developed for systems back then were made in C, and one big difference between C and C# is that C# is OOP but C isn't.

When I found out about this in the past it always kept me thinking what approach was taken for game development in C ? In C# OOP is pretty much the main approach used in game development, so how was it done in C ? Game Libraries with OOP functionality ?

I've been reading that C can have OOP functionality written to it which makes sense seeing that we have C#, and a lot of programming languages at its core is derived from C.

How much different was the approach for game development? Also, disregarding things in C like hardware specific code and the rest of the intermediate language worries, how much harder was it ?

**UPDATE**

I'm looking for a general answer. Nothing too deep because I understand that this is too broad of a question. So let me narrow it down to...How does non OOP look in game development ? For example, How would drawing multiple objects of the same functionality look in C code

Comment: Pain... lots of pain. Unfortunately, even having done game programming in C, I'm not sure how to answer this as it is awfully broad. Could you narrow down the scope a bit?

Comment: Considering the answer is probably "It depends" big time, asking in programmers.stackexchange may bring you more luck. But yes, as BradleyDotNET said, very painfully. How familiar are you with C?

Comment: Many `if` statements.  See for instance [NetHack 3.4.3: Download the Source](http://nethack.org/v343/download-src.html).

Comment: @dbc Don't forget about Giant Switch Statements of Doom

Comment: What features of OOP are beneficial in game programming? I can only think of single inheritance and polymorphism, both of which you can very easily implement in C. But you can also read actual source code from C games, like DOOM: https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM

Comment: I cannot tell, when I programmed games, Assembler was the way to go.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Pain? Not necessarily. At least the code was not bloat with tons of overloaded - thus unused - methods, etc. But it depends on how you programmed back then. 80ies and 90ies game programmer often did not have the experience and hardly knew how to organize their source code, let alone a whole project.

Comment: And C is **not** an "intermediate language". Actually that applies more to C++, C#, etc., as these do not provide _full_ OOP features. That would include strong dynamic typing, metaclasses (clases being first class objects), etc.

Comment: @cost: Poor design is no domain of a specific language.

Comment: It is/was possible to write good, maintainable code without OOP. See "Structured Programming" and "Structured Design", aimed at reducing coupling and increasing cohesion

Comment: @Olaf Pain for the same reasons *any* lower-level language is painful. The lack of all that overhead means you are usually doing a *ton* more work.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Or you can concentrate on the basics and do not have to learn tons of libraries, etc. Or waste time to search them if there is a function available already for what you want to do, instead of just writing on your own. There are so many library functions you could write faster on your own, than find them. But if you do, then some idot just asks why you did rewrite this and that, just because he happens to know that particular library.

Comment: One result of games in OOP are Tetris-alike games which require a Radeon 280X+, quad core CPU and 8GiB RAM.

Comment: @Olaf I was taught that C# was a high-level language

Comment: I have no experience in C, and I don't plan on learning it at the moment. So I'm not too familiar with it

Comment: Also, I got pretty much a good idea of how things work reading the comments. I really wasn't looking for a extremely detailed answer. All I really was looking for something generic. 

For example, I just want to know how non-OOP code would look in game development, seeing that C# pretty covers up a lot being a high level language and all...

Comment: With astronomically lower budgets, lower runtime resource requirements, and much more entertaining results. :-)

Comment: I think its best for me to take a look at source codes of really simple games made in C to get an idea of how non-OOP looks. Thanks guys I appreciate the answers!

Comment: @izuhu: You cannot judge a language until you have at least some experience in it. And: High level is relative. There is always a higher level. C is a true procedural, modular language. The worst (here) is it is missing user-namespaces - per module/compilation unit would be sufficient. Not that I am happy with all its quirks, but if you know it and use a good coding style, you can work pretty fast and stable. Depending on the project, even faster than in most OOP languages.

Comment: About your edit: `Object objs[10]; ... for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) draw(&objs[i]);`? Not more code (even less?) than for OOP actually.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for the info and clarity. I never really was judging the language. I just was stating what I read and was taught about the language. :)

Comment: "If you only know how to use a hammer, every problem looks like a nail." Perhaps the people who told you that should try to get a wider picture? Even assembler still has its niche.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There too many points in your question to address, but I recommend watching [this series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaTznQhurW5AaiYPbhEA-KA) In it, an experienced game dev builds a full game in C with no libraries.

In the grand scheme of things OOP is just an abstraction that sometimes makes things easier. In the really old days, developers would not even use C and instead would write in assembly for the specific system.

Comment: Game development in assembler on Atari ST was actually much fun.

Comment: @Olaf You have a very odd idea of *fun* ;)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: Not necessarily. It was a very different time back then. I did not say I would do it again that way - but not necessarily in C#/C++ either. The first is bloat, the latter is a syntax-nightmare. Too bad Python is too slow for full 3D games. For casual games, I'd definitively test it, however.

Comment: @Olaf From what I've read about old Atari development, the greatest saving grace was to comment your code well.

Comment: @cost: I did not just Atari, but also C64, CPC. I still have my Atari code; the others are very likely lost :-(. However, the 68000 (well - macro-assembler, that makes a great difference) has one of the best machine languages and a very good assembler syntax. No comparison with that rubbish x86.

Comment: @TylerReid I find it funny that you posted this. I tune into this guy's stream from time to time lol

Comment: @cost: Regarding commenting code: That is a common recommendation and not specific to Atari. And, of course, you should document assembler code very good. But why would that be specific for Atari-ST?

Comment: @Olaf It wasn't really geared specifically towards the Atari-ST, as poorly commented code can (and does) exist everywhere. Reading the Atari experiences of others (Atari programming was all before my time), I noticed a common theme of "missing comments made for a very bad time"

Comment: @cost: Well, I've got first class experience. And, yes, not commenting assembler is pretty bad. I still have a very interesting labyrinth-generator code for 68000 here (own code) which is actually poorly documented. OTOH, I now could write such code from scratch easier than analyse that code, because of such experiments and may others, I gained the experience I have today.

Comment: @Olaf: Feeling envy now. From what I remember I was playing with some shitty Atari BASIC on 65XE (I was eight years old). The assembly instructions were too mysterious for me.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: I actuylly stated with digital logic (TTL: gates, buttons, LEDs) at the age of 12. Then programming (machine language, no actual hardware), Atari came about 1986 (I was busy with CPC until then). The duality - hardware/software - I still try to cultivate. Sadly, many customers want one or the other, so I tend to start in a project as either. But most times, I somehow get into the position to contribute to both fields - funny enough.

Comment: I still remember how confused (and upset) I was that I could not easily define the loading address of my program code on the ST, as I was used to on the 8 bit machines. Drove me quite crazy until I accepted it - and never cared thereafter. Man, I fell old now:-}